# Como variar parâmetros de uma equação?

Tags: r, loop, parâmetros

Para uma equação do tipo `y = ax + b`, possuimos dois valores para `a` e dois para `b`, ou seja, possuímos quatro equações diferentes. 
Ja temos um código que nos retorna os valores de `x` e `y` para cada equação separadamente. Queremos saber se existe uma maneira de realizar um `loop` que nos retorne os valores respectivos de cada `x` e `y` quando variamos os valores de "a" e "b". Ou seja, como encontrar `y1, y2, y3, y4, x1, x2, x3 e x4`(para cada combinação de a e b) sem ter que rodar o código quatro vezes.

obs: o programa utilizado é o R

Comment: Mariana, coloque um exemplo do que você já fez. Você quer achar tanto `y` quanto `x` ou só achar `y` para um dado `x`? Porque da forma que você colocou você tem duas variáveis e somente uma equação, então são infinitas soluções de `x` e `y`.

Comment: Olá, Carlos, na verdade a equação representa uma regressão econométrica e temos uma fórmula para encontrar tanto os valores de x quanto os valores de y, que é muito grande para ser colocada aqui. 
Se supusermos um x fixo, com os parâmetros variando, como encontraríamos y sem ter que rodar o código quatro vezes?

Comment: Se não for possível colocar o código original, coloque um código "ilustrativo" que exemplifique o problema, pois a pergunta fica ambígua da forma como está. Mas acho que entendi o que você quer, coloquei uma resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponha que você tenha dois parâmetros `a`, dois parâmetros `b` e um valor de `x`:

```
a<- c(1,2)
b <-c(3,4)
x <- 10
```

Você quer encontrar todas os `y` possíveis com as quatro combinações dos parâmetros, dado o valor de `x`. Então a primeira coisa a fazer é gerar essas combinações:

```
parametros <- merge(a, b, by=NULL)
names(parametros) <-c("a", "b")
parametros
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 3
3 1 4
4 2 4
```

Agora definimos a função que gera o valor de `y` e podemos usar `mapply` para encontrar todos os valores de `y` das combinações dos parâmetros:

```
y<-mapply(function(x,a,b) y=a*x +b, x=x, a=parametros[1,], b=parametros[,2])
y
[1] 13 33 14 34
```